# XPath for attribute value that ends with a string?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm having trouble selecting an element with an attribute that ends with a certain value.

XML looks like

```
<root>
<object name="1_2"><attribute name="show" value="example"></object>
<object name="1_1"><attribute name="show" value="example"></object>
<object name="2_1"><attribute name="show" value="example"></object>
</root>
```

So I need to extract all values from attributes in objects ends with `_1`, how can I do that?

I did this code

```
 XmlNodeList childnodes = xRoot.SelectNodes("//Object[@Name='1_1']");
        foreach (XmlNode n in childnodes)
            Console.WriteLine(n.SelectSingleNode("Attribute[@Name='show']").OuterXml);
```

but I can't find how to search for the part of attributes name and how to get the exact value of target parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that XML and XPath are case sensitive, so `Object` is different than `object`, and `Name` is different than `name`.

### XPath 2.0

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
//object[ends-with(@name,'_1')]
```

will select all `object` elements whose `name` attribute value ends with `_1`.

### XPath 1.0

XPath 1.0 lacks the `ends-with()` function but can achieve the same result with a bit more work:

```
ends-with($s, $e) ≡ (substring($s, string-length($s) - string-length($e) +1) = $e)
```

Applied to your case where `$s` is `@name` and `$e` is `'_1'`, the above simplifies to this expression:

```
//object[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - 1) = '_1']
```

Comment: The XPath 1.0 syntax is incorrect. The `string-length(@name)` is duplicated. It should instead be `//object[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - 1) = '_1']` as @jan-peter-vos has it in the other answer.

Comment: @Metalogic: You are correct.  Good catch!  Answer updated to fix that mistake and add an explanation regarding how to do `ends-with()` in XPath 1.0 in general.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If `C#` supports `XPath 2.0` you should be able to use:

```
XmlNodeList childnodes = xRoot.SelectNodes("//object[ends-with(@name, '_1')]");
```

if not then a slightly longer version should work:

```
XmlNodeList childnodes = xRoot.SelectNodes("//object[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - 1) = '_1']");
```

Also your xml is not valid as you need to close the `attribute` elements:

```
<root>
  <object name="1_2"><attribute name="show" value="example"/></object>
  <object name="1_1"><attribute name="show" value="example"/></object>
  <object name="2_1"><attribute name="show" value="example"/></object>
</root>
```